# What is the difference of IndexPath, IndexScan and IndexScanState in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

When I read the source code (in `node.h`), I find there are those three nodes related to an index scan. However, I'm not sure what they actually stand for.

I guess they may belong to different stages during the parse-analyze-plan-execute procedure, but I want to ask which part does each of them actually belongs to, and what different information do they have?

Another concern of me is that will any of them be preserved in a view? I remember that PostgreSQL will persist some kind of parsed tree for a view in some system tables -- will any of the index-related node be contained in that structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexPath` (defined in `src/include/nodes/pathnodes.h`) is a node in a *path*. `IndexScan` (defined in `src/include/nodes/plannodes.h`) is a node in a query *plan*. The difference is explained in `src/backend/optimizer/README`:

```
During the planning/optimizing process, we build "Path" trees representing
the different ways of doing a query.  We select the cheapest Path that
generates the desired relation and turn it into a Plan to pass to the
executor.  (There is pretty nearly a one-to-one correspondence between the
Path and Plan trees, but Path nodes omit info that won't be needed during
planning, and include info needed for planning that won't be needed by the
executor.)
```

An `IndexScanState` (defined in `src/include/nodes/execnodes.h`) contains the state that is used by the query executor when it executes and `IndexScan`.